# iOS Facebook app stuck in logged in state - how to log that user out?

Tags: ios, facebook, login-screen

My wife was on one of her Facebook accounts on the Facebook app on my iPad one day. And when she went to log out, instead of the normal login screen, it now says `Logged in as Xxx Yyyy` with *Xxx Yyyy* being substituted here for my wife's account.

There’s a link below that that says `Not Xxx Yyyy?`, which gets you to the normal login screen so you can log into other accounts; but what I want to know is how do we get that account logged out properly so that the Facebook app goes to the normal login screen directly?

This is on iOS 8.2. One of the comments suggested I sign in with another account and log out with 'Remember me' unchecked, but I don't see a 'Remember me' check box on either login or logout. Also, this is the Facebook app itself, not the Settings app.

**Update:** Instead of the `Logged in as` link, there's now two pictures, one for each of my wife's accounts, with the account names below them. (And, there's a `Log in as a different user` link below.) It seems that the FB app is being changed to allow one tap logins or something. But there should still be a way to actually log out in such a way as to force the password entry next time, shouldn't there? I'm concerned that there's now this state that the app can be left in where someone can just click and go right into one of the accounts on the initial screen without typing a password. (Granted, the FB site has a 'keep me logged in' feature when you log into it from a browser, but at least there, when you log out, you're *actually logged out*.)

**Update 2:** As it turns out, the Facebook app's new behaviour is, indeed, a new feature for logging into your account(s) with one tab and no need to type your password. (When I logged into my account, I was greeted with a little dialogue that asked if I wanted my account to be saved like that (with an optional 4-digit passcode). I was able to get rid of one of the accounts from the app (the first one that showed up) by going to the Settings app and deleting the account from the Facebook app. For whatever reason, the other account isn't showing up there. Nor is there any option to add a passcode after the fact. Anyone know if there's a way to get at (and delete) all accounts that have been saved by the FB app?

Comment: Log in a different account without the "remember me" option checked, then log out of that account.

Comment: Web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress are off topic. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Is she logged into Facebook through the Settings app? (Settings > Facebook) Also, what version of iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I still had the profile pics (or, rather, the one that I wasn't able to delete from the Setup app) visible in the Facebook app, I noticed that there was a link at the bottom of the screen called 'Login Settings' or something along those lines. Tapping that brought up a dialogue that lists the accounts that are set for instant login, so I was able to delete the other account from there (you can set or change passcodes from there, too, if that's your preference), and I'm back to the more secure old behaviour of needing to type in the passwords for all of our accounts.